# Avoiding intermediate dlply step when starting with a dataframe and ending with a dataframe

Tags: r, plyr, statistics-bootstrap

I am using plyr to perform a bootstrapping function on subsets of a dataset.

Because the boot function creates a list object, I am currently using dlply to store the output of the function, then a ddply to get just the parts of the bootfunction that I want out

My example dataset is as follows:

```
dat = data.frame(x = rnorm(10, sd = 1),y = rnorm(10, sd = 1),z = rep(c("SppA", "SppB", "SppC", "SppD", "SppE"), 2),u = rep(c("SiteA", "SiteB"), 5))
```

the exact function isn't terribly important, but for the sake of reproducibility, here is the function I'm using:

```
boot_fun = function(x,i) {
  i = sample(1:24, 24, replace = TRUE)
  ts1 = mean(x[i,"x"])
  ts2 = sample(x[i,"y"])
  mean(ts1) - mean(ts2)
}
```

My plyr function is the following:

```
temp = dlply(dat, c("z", "u"), summarise, boot_object = boot(dat, boot_fun, R = 1000))
```

Since what I want out of the boot object is the mean and CI, I then perform the following plyr function:

```
temp2 = ldply(temp, summarise, mean = mean(boot$t), lowCI = quantile(boot$t, 0.025), highCI = quantile(boot$t, 0.975))
```

This works and accomplishes exactly what I want it to (although with an error about subsetting which doesn't seem to affect anything I care about), but I feel like there should be a way to skip the intermediate dlply step.

-edit- to clarify on what I'm trying to do if I didn't need to be splitting the groups

If I was manually splitting instead of using plyr, it would look something like the following:

```
temp = boot(dat[dat$z == "SppA" & dat$u == "SiteA",], boot_fun, R = 1000)
temp2$mean = mean(temp$t)
temp2$lowCI = quantile(temp$t, 0.025)
temp2$highCI = quantile(temp$t, 0.975)
```

If I didn't care about the groups at all and just wanted to do this to the whole group it would be something like

```
temp = boot(dat, boot_fun, R = 1000)
temp2$mean = mean(temp$t)
temp2$lowCI = quantile(temp$t, 0.025)
temp2$highCI = quantile(temp$t, 0.975)
```

Comment: Could you break down your `dlply` statement into understandable steps? For instance, you create `boot_object`, which you then summarise?

Comment: @Chi Pak  Yes, basically. The boot object stores a lot of information including some of the data used in it's creation (like the seed, the number of iterations, the starting data, etc.). The first plyr function is just creating and storing the boot object. The second plyr function uses just the part of the boot object that is the generated data (the 1000 sampled replicates, stores as "t" in the boot object) and generates the mean of those and the 95% confidence intervals.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand...I get an error when I try to reproduce your example...how would you perform the first `plyr` statement with the first row of `dat`?  Something like `temp <- summarise(boot..[dat,1])`?

Comment: @Chi Pak Are you asking how I would do it if I was manually splitting rather than using plyr to split the groups? It would basically be `temp = boot(dat[dat$z == "SppA" & dat$u == "SiteA", c("x", "y")], boot_fun, R = 1000)`  
The second step would be `temp2$mean = mean(temp$t)
temp2$lowCI = quantile(temp$t, 0.025)
temp2$HighCI = quantile(temp$t, 0.975)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is not reproducible by me.

When I do `temp = boot(dat, boot_fun, R = 1000)`, I get a **`WARNING`**:

```
ORDINARY NONPARAMETRIC BOOTSTRAP
Call:
boot(data = dat, statistic = boot_fun, R = 1000)
Bootstrap Statistics :
WARNING: All values of t1* are NA
```

I think your current code is pretty efficient, but if you're looking for other possibilities, you could try `tidyverse` to *1)* `group_by` the relevant columns, *2)* `nest` the relevant data for bootstrapping, *3)* run your bootstrap with the nested data, *4)* isolate the statistics you desire, then *5)* return to a *normal* data frame

```
library(boot)
library(tidyverse)
dat1 <- dat %>%
          group_by(z,u) %>%
          nest() %>%
          mutate(data=map(data,~boot(.x, boot_fun, R=1000))) %>%
          mutate(data=map(data,~data.frame(mean=mean(.x$t), lowCI=quantile(.x$t, 0.025), highCI=quantile(.x$t,0.975)))) %>%
          unnest(data)
```